# Find all the HTML tags via regex (except br and li tags)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am facing one issue related to regex in my `Javascript` code. I am looking for a regex which can match all the `HTMl` tags except `br` tags and li (including `ol` and `ul`).

So far I have the regex that can detect HTML tags except br tags. It is as following

```
(<((?!br)[^>]+(.*?)?)>)
```

Need help with `<li>`,`<ol>` and `<ul>`tags. (including closing tags as well)

Here is the sample text for checking.

```html
<ol>
  <li>hi</li>
</ol>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>

hello <br /> world <br /> :)

'https://www.youtube.com'

 Normal text: should not match!!

'https://www.hotmail.com'

<img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" />

<img src="/" />
```

I am using https://regexr.com/ for testing the regex.

Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this. Why not using perhaps an HTML parser?

Comment: Regex is [notoriously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) the wrong tool for this job.  (Your existing regex will fail if there is any parent tag wrapping the content you want to keep, for example.). HTML is complex structured data, you're much better off using the DOM tools designed for working with it instead of forcing it through a string parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old adage has it, if you want to solve your problem with Regex, you are going to end up with two problems. While admittedly a powerful tool, in situations like this, Regex should be used only as a last resort.

Try the below:

```
const getAllNodesExceptBrAndLi = htmlString => {
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = htmlString;
  const allNodes = template.content.querySelectorAll('*');

  return [...allNodes].filter(node => node.tagName !== 'BR' && node.tagName !== 'LI');
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/(<((?!br)(?!ol)(?!\/ol)(?!ul)(?!\/ul)(?!li)(?!\/li)[^>]+(.*?)?)>)/ig
```

Comment: This will fail once html-attributes are added to the mix. If you care about robust code, the solution proposed by Przemek is a better choice.